# macOS Eclipse does not find OpenJDK

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

Because of the Oracle Java licensing, I have removed Java from my macOS 10.14.3 and installed OpenJDK8.

```sh
AB-iMac:~ AndyBrunner$ cat .bash_profile 
export JAVA_HOME=/Applications/Java/OpenJDK/JDK1.8/Contents/Home/bin/
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME:$PATH

AB-iMac:~ AndyBrunner$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Applications/Java/OpenJDK/JDK1.8/Contents/Home/bin/

AB-iMac:~ AndyBrunner$ echo $PATH
/Applications/Java/OpenJDK/JDK1.8/Contents/Home/bin/:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public

AB-iMac:~ AndyBrunner$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_202"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-b08)
Eclipse OpenJ9 VM (build openj9-0.12.1, JRE 1.8.0 Mac OS X amd64-64-Bit Compressed References 20190205_147 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
OpenJ9   - 90dd8cb40
OMR      - d2f4534b
JCL      - d002501a90 based on jdk8u202-b08)
```

But when I start Eclipse, the error message "Failed to create the Java Virtual Machine." pops up.

What is needed to tell Eclipse to use the OpenJDK?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You specify the VM to use in `eclipse.ini`.

> On a Mac OS X system, you can find eclipse.ini by right-clicking (or
>   Ctrl+click) on the Eclipse executable in Finder, choose Show Package
>   Contents, and then locate eclipse.ini in the Eclipse folder under
>   Contents. The path is often
>
> /Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/eclipse.ini For versions of
>   Mac OS X 10.7+ the location is something like
>   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines//Contents/Home/bin
>
> For example, the latest JDK 1.8 (as of July 2015) is
>   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/bin

https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#-vm_value:_Mac_OS_X_Example

So in your case:

```
-vm
/Applications/Java/OpenJDK/JDK1.8/Contents/Home/bin/
```

Comment: I find it *very* irritating that in 2021 we still have to hack `eclipse.ini` in order for Eclipse to be able to start up on MacOS. There are plenty of ways to auto-locate JVMs on MacOS and Eclipse could easily show the user a list of those JVMs on startup if the one specified in `eclipse.ini` can't be found/launched for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Setting environment variables in bash has no effect on Applications launched from Finder.

The easiest solution is to simply install OpenJDK into /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines or into $HOME/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines (i.e. create the folder if it doesn't exist and extract the tar there)